# How to set initialState with createAEntityAdapter

Tags: react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have constant data and i want to set initial state. I am using createEntityAdapter. How can i define initialState ?

```
import { createSlice, createEntityAdapter } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const cardAdaptor = createEntityAdapter();
const cardSlice = createSlice({
  name: "cards",
  initialState: {},
  reducers: {}
});
export default cardSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: What does the constant data look like? What do you want to get?

Answer (score 4):

The entity adapter has a `getInitialState` function which it uses to create an empty initial state.  If you call that function with no values, then the initial state is an empty array of `ids` and an empty dictionary of `entities`, ie.

```
cardAdapter.getInitialState()
```

creates

```
{
    ids: [],
    entities: {}
}
```

---

You can add any arbitrary initial data by passing an argument to `getInitialState`.  You provide an object and those properties will be included on the top level of your state.

```
cardAdapter.getInitialState({
    someProperty: 0,
    otherProperty: []
}));
```

creates

```
{
    ids: [],
    entities: {},
    someProperty: 0,
    otherProperty: []
}
```

---

It is also possible to override the initial `ids` and `entities` properties this way.  I would advise against that unless you are sure that you know what you are doing, as you could have ids with no entity or vice-versa.

Comment: how can I override ids and entities properties ?  can u do an example?